# How do I configure Google Calendar so that it renders events, longer than 24hrs, in hour cells?

Tags: google-calendar

I use Google Calendar intensively and it really helps organizing my daily work. But I still can't get used to the way it renders events longer than 24 hours. For example, here is a test calendar showing two events: 23h30m (green; left) and 24h00m (red; right). I really find the former, green, much easier to read, whilst the latter, red, merely makes me lost understanding when it begins and when it ends. As you can see, the first yellow event clearly overlaps the green event, but the second one is visually lost and it's not clear if it overlaps the red event (it does just because I know the duration of the red event).

Is there a way to configure the calendar rendering so that it renders all (even long) events in the hour cells?

[image: overlapping events]